# How to make combinations and random sample in Python

Tags: python

I would like to make combinations and random selections of all combinations. The output is tuple but I have no idea how to random select the certain number of the tuple.

Codes

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from random import choice, sample

list1 = ("Mon", "Tue","Wed","Tru","Fri","Sat","Sun")
for i in combinations(list1, 3):
    print(i,end=' ')
```

Output

```
('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed') ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Tru') ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Fri') ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Sat') ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Sun') ('Mon', 'Wed', 'Tru') ('Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri') ('Mon', 'Wed', 'Sat') ('Mon', 'Wed', 'Sun') ('Mon', 'Tru', 'Fri') ('Mon', 'Tru', 'Sat') ('Mon', 'Tru', 'Sun') ('Mon', 'Fri', 'Sat') ('Mon', 'Fri', 'Sun') ('Mon', 'Sat', 'Sun') ('Tue', 'Wed', 'Tru') ('Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri') ('Tue', 'Wed', 'Sat') ('Tue', 'Wed', 'Sun') ('Tue', 'Tru', 'Fri') ('Tue', 'Tru', 'Sat') ('Tue', 'Tru', 'Sun') ('Tue', 'Fri', 'Sat') ('Tue', 'Fri', 'Sun') ('Tue', 'Sat', 'Sun') ('Wed', 'Tru', 'Fri') ('Wed', 'Tru', 'Sat') ('Wed', 'Tru', 'Sun') ('Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat') ('Wed', 'Fri', 'Sun') ('Wed', 'Sat', 'Sun') ('Tru', 'Fri', 'Sat') ('Tru', 'Fri', 'Sun') ('Tru', 'Sat', 'Sun') ('Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
```

What I tried as follows

```
S =sample(i,4)
print(S)
```

Output

```
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

The expected output as follows

```
('Wed', 'Sat', 'Sun') ('Tru', 'Fri', 'Sat') ('Tru', 'Fri', 'Sun') ('Tru', 'Sat', 'Sun')
```

Comment: Instead of printing the combinations, you need to save them to a list, then sample from the list

Answer (score 1):

instead of printing append it to other list

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from random import choice, sample

list1 = ("Mon", "Tue","Wed","Tru","Fri","Sat","Sun")
list2 = []
for i in combinations(list1, 3):
    list2.append(i)

S =sample(list2,4)
print(S)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
list1 = ["Mon", "Tue","Wed","Tru","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
def make_combo(len1,len2):
    return [tuple([random.choice(list1) for i in range(len2)]) for i in range(len1)]
```

this makes a list of len1 tuples of len2 length

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a single tuple, not the whole generated sequence. You'd have to first create a list from the `combinations()` output, then sample from that list:

```
weekdays = ("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
S = sample(list(combinations(weekdays, 3)), 4)
```

Note: I corrected the spelling of `Thu` in that list and picked a friendlier variable name.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from random import sample
>>> weekdays = ("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
>>> sample(list(combinations(weekdays, 3)), 4)
[('Mon', 'Tue', 'Sun'), ('Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun'), ('Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri'), ('Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun')]
```

However, I'd instead create random samples from the names of the week and add them to a set to ensure you have unique tuples, until you have your desired size:

```
def sample_combinations(choices, size, count):
    collected = {tuple(sample(weekdays, size)) for _ in range(count)}
    while len(collected) < count:
        collected.add(tuple(sample(weekdays, size)))
    return list(collected)

S = sample_combinations(weekdays, 3, 4)
```

which produces the same output, with no repeated tuples:

```
>>> sample_combinations(weekdays, 3, 4)
[('Tue', 'Fri', 'Wed'), ('Sun', 'Sat', 'Fri'), ('Mon', 'Fri', 'Thu'), ('Tue', 'Mon', 'Sat')]
```

That's likely to be more efficient as it avoids having to generate all possible permutations up front. This becomes more important the larger the number of possible combinations there are. For your weekdays example, there are only 35 possible combinations, but other input parameters (names to select from, size of the combinations tuple) could produce millions of possible combinations.

For example, if you were to select 3 *lowercase ASCII letters*, you'd need to generate a list of 2600 tuples before you could sample 4 from those. Add in uppercase ASCII letters and the count goes up to 22100. With the 10 digits you need to process 39711 tuples, etc. But the above function only needs to generate 4 unique combinations, nothing more. Chances are it won't have to iterate further in case there were duplicates.

That makes it *much, much faster* for larger number of combinations:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(
...     "sample(list(combinations(ascii_letters, 3)), 4)",
...     "from itertools import combinations; from random import sample; from string import ascii_letters",
...     number=10**3
... )   # 1000 repeats, so result is in milliseconds / execution
1.1539382990158629
>>> timeit.timeit(
    "sample_combinations(ascii_letters, 3, 4)",
    "from __main__ import sample_combinations; from string import ascii_letters",
    number=10**6
)  # 100.000 repeats, so 1000 times more, microseconds / execution
14.198360272974242
```

With ASCII letters (22100 possible combinations), loading all those combinations then using `random.sample()` takes 1.539 milliseconds, but using the above function takes 14.2 *microseconds*. That's about 80 times faster.